# Enabling PHP in Apache

Tags: php, apache

I just want to start by saying thank you in advance, this has been driving me crazy.
I installed PHP, and Apache on my raspberry pi and am doing some home projects. When I go to my website it pulls up HTML fine, but when opening my php files it just displays my code.

Steps Taken:

1. Verified PHP is indeed installed on my server.
2. I disabled mpm_event, and enabled mpm_prefork, and then also enabled php7.3 and restarted apache.
3. I looked inside the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and couldn't find any LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so line anywhere. I saw some other answers point to this being the issue but I tried adding the line (using php7) into the conf file but still no luck. Not sure if this is necessary just saw other posts mention it so I gave it a try!

Not sure if this is relevant, but when I enable mpm_prefork, and php7.3 the website doesn't display code anymore and it gives me an HTTP ERROR 412 "The page isn't working"

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with PHP, Apache, Try setting it up using this site : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md

I hope you get it working, if any questions appear during installation, I can help.